# Travel time in Google Sheets using Google Directions API

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, directions

For these inputs:

1. Origin
2. Destination
3. Arrival Time

I want two Google Sheets formulas that result in showing:

1. the distance in miles
2. travel times (driving, with traffic).

It'd be simple formulas that reference cells in the sheet that goes something like

```
=TravelTime(Origin,Destination,Arrive)
```

I've set up a Google Directions API account and pieced together this so far, but I have no idea how to get the URL to work and how to get the formula to return the outputs I want.

```
function TravelTime(Origin,Destination,Arrive) {

   var Origin
   var Destination
   var Arrive

   var apiUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='&Origin&'&destination='&Destination&'&key=MYKEY';

}
```

Comment: This question is very broad. It looks like you need to read some tutorials Google Apps Script, making REST API requests, and working with JSON. The Stack Overflow community will be able to better help you when you have a specific coding question that includes a [mcve] and shows a solid attempt to code this solution.

Comment: And also look at TomTom.  Has 2500 free transactions per day.  I use it to show  travel times to our sites, even shows delay times due to traffic and such.  it also does distance, departure and arrival times, 
 https://developer.tomtom.com/store/maps-api

Comment: Thanks guys! With your help I got it to work with Google Maps. I checked out TomTom and it looks similar. If I run out of the credit from Google APIs I might need to look at pricing between the two.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to call an [external API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external).

Try doing something like this:

```
function TravelTime(Origin,Destination,Arrive) {
  var apiUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='&Origin&'&destination='&Destination&'&key=MYKEY';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json); //your final object, get the data you want here then return it.
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! With your help I got it to work. One thing was I was using & instead of + to concatenate the elements of the URL.